# PHP, MySql. List with subitems

Tags: php, mysql

I have a database saving data about courses we deliver. So I have 2 tables, one to save the course details, 2 to save the participants details and in each record I am saving which course they are a member of.

Table 1 (CourseInfo):
ID, CourseName, CourseStartDay, and so on

Table 2 (UserInfo):
ID, FirstName, and so on, CourseID

Now, I want displayed on my page all courses available and in the sub-list all participants of this particular course.

Like this:

- Course 1

  - John
  - Jack
  - Stacey
  - Rebecca

- Course 2

  - Adam
  - Leah
  - Sara

My code:

```
<?php require_once('Connections/JPT.php'); ?>
<?php
if (!isset($_SESSION)) {
  session_start();
}
$MM_authorizedUsers = "1";
$MM_donotCheckaccess = "true";

// *** Restrict Access To Page: Grant or deny access to this page
function isAuthorized($strUsers, $strGroups, $UserName, $UserGroup) { 
  // For security, start by assuming the visitor is NOT authorized. 
  $isValid = False; 

  // When a visitor has logged into this site, the Session variable MM_Username set equal to their username. 
  // Therefore, we know that a user is NOT logged in if that Session variable is blank. 
  if (!empty($UserName)) { 
    // Besides being logged in, you may restrict access to only certain users based on an ID established when they login. 
    // Parse the strings into arrays. 
    $arrUsers = Explode(",", $strUsers); 
    $arrGroups = Explode(",", $strGroups); 
    if (in_array($UserName, $arrUsers)) { 
      $isValid = true; 
    } 
    // Or, you may restrict access to only certain users based on their username. 
    if (in_array($UserGroup, $arrGroups)) { 
      $isValid = true; 
    } 
    if (($strUsers == "") && true) { 
      $isValid = true; 
    } 
  } 
  return $isValid; 
}

$MM_restrictGoTo = "index.php";
if (!((isset($_SESSION['MM_Username'])) && (isAuthorized("",$MM_authorizedUsers, $_SESSION['MM_Username'], $_SESSION['MM_UserGroup'])))) {   
  $MM_qsChar = "?";
  $MM_referrer = $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];
  if (strpos($MM_restrictGoTo, "?")) $MM_qsChar = "&";
  if (isset($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']) && strlen($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']) > 0) 
  $MM_referrer .= "?" . $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'];
  $MM_restrictGoTo = $MM_restrictGoTo. $MM_qsChar . "accesscheck=" . urlencode($MM_referrer);
  header("Location: ". $MM_restrictGoTo); 
  exit;
}
?>
<?php
if (!function_exists("GetSQLValueString")) {
function GetSQLValueString($theValue, $theType, $theDefinedValue = "", $theNotDefinedValue = "") 
{
  if (PHP_VERSION < 6) {
    $theValue = get_magic_quotes_gpc() ? stripslashes($theValue) : $theValue;
  }

  $theValue = function_exists("mysql_real_escape_string") ? mysql_real_escape_string($theValue) : mysql_escape_string($theValue);

  switch ($theType) {
    case "text":
      $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? "'" . $theValue . "'" : "NULL";
      break;    
    case "long":
    case "int":
      $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? intval($theValue) : "NULL";
      break;
    case "double":
      $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? doubleval($theValue) : "NULL";
      break;
    case "date":
      $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? "'" . $theValue . "'" : "NULL";
      break;
    case "defined":
      $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? $theDefinedValue : $theNotDefinedValue;
      break;
  }
  return $theValue;
}
}

$colname_UserDetails = "-1";
if (isset($_SESSION['MM_Username'])) {
  $colname_UserDetails = $_SESSION['MM_Username'];
}
mysql_select_db($database_JPT, $JPT);
$query_UserDetails = sprintf("SELECT * FROM UserInfo WHERE Username = %s", GetSQLValueString($colname_UserDetails, "text"));
$UserDetails = mysql_query($query_UserDetails, $JPT) or die(mysql_error());
$row_UserDetails = mysql_fetch_assoc($UserDetails);
$totalRows_UserDetails = mysql_num_rows($UserDetails);

mysql_select_db($database_JPT, $JPT);
$query_GroupList = "SELECT * FROM GroupList WHERE Status = 'A' ORDER BY ID DESC";
$GroupList = mysql_query($query_GroupList, $JPT) or die(mysql_error());
$row_GroupList = mysql_fetch_assoc($GroupList);
$totalRows_GroupList = mysql_num_rows($GroupList);

//  $group_id = $row_GroupList['ID'];
//mysql_select_db($database_JPT, $JPT);
//$query_PartcipantsList = sprintf("SELECT FirstName, Surname, Username, EmailAddress, HouseNumber, Address1, Address2, City, PostCode, Country, Phone, Mobile, ReferedBy, PaymentMethod, ChargeAmount, PaidAmount, GroupID, Status, UserType FROM UserInfo WHERE Status='A' AND UserType=2 AND GroupID=%s", GetSQLValueString($group_id, "int"));
//$PartcipantsList = mysql_query($query_PartcipantsList, $JPT) or die(mysql_error());
//$row_PartcipantsList = mysql_fetch_assoc($PartcipantsList);
//$totalRows_PartcipantsList = mysql_num_rows($PartcipantsList);
//$particpant_FirstName = $row_PartcipantsList['FirstName'];

$colname_UserType = "-1";
if (isset($row_UserDetails['UserType'])) {
$colname_UserType = $row_UserDetails['UserType'];
}
    if ($colname_UserType != 1) {
        header('location: linklist.php');
  exit;
    }



?>
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>List of Partcipants</title>
</head>

<body>
  <?php do { 

  ?>
<table border="1">
  <tr>
    <td>Group ID</td>
    <td>Group Name</td>
    <td>Start Date</td>
    <td>Notes</td>
  </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><?php echo $row_GroupList['ID']; ?></td>
      <td><?php echo $row_GroupList['GroupName']; ?></td>
      <td><?php echo $row_GroupList['StartDate']; ?></td>
      <td><?php echo $row_GroupList['Notes']; ?></td>
    </tr>

</table>    
<p/>

<table border="1">
  <tr>
    <td width="175px">Name</td>
    <td>Email Address</td>
    <td>Address</td>
    <td>Country</td>
    <td>Phone</td>
    <td>Refered By</td>
    <td>Payment Method</td>
    <td>Charge Amount</td>
    <td width="50px">Paid Amount</td>
    <td width="50px">Group</td>
  </tr>
  <?php do { 

  $group_id_new = $row_GroupList['ID'];
mysql_select_db($database_JPT, $JPT);
$query_PartcipantsList = sprintf("SELECT FirstName, Surname, Username, EmailAddress, HouseNumber, Address1, Address2, City, PostCode, Country, Phone, Mobile, ReferedBy, PaymentMethod, ChargeAmount, PaidAmount, GroupID, Status, UserType FROM UserInfo WHERE Status='A' AND UserType=2 AND GroupID=%s", GetSQLValueString($group_id_new, "int"));
$PartcipantsList = mysql_query($query_PartcipantsList, $JPT) or die(mysql_error());
$row_PartcipantsList = mysql_fetch_assoc($PartcipantsList);
$totalRows_PartcipantsList = mysql_num_rows($PartcipantsList);


  //take in all fields in a variable with a short name
  $pt_Add1 = $row_PartcipantsList['HouseNumber'];
  $pt_Add2 = $row_PartcipantsList['Address1'];
  $pt_Add3 = $row_PartcipantsList['Address2'];
  $pt_Add4 = $row_PartcipantsList['City'];
  $pt_Add5 = $row_PartcipantsList['PostCode'];

  //create variables with commas to concatenate the address
  $pt_result_Add1 = ($pt_Add1 != "") ? $pt_Add1 . " " : "";
  $pt_result_Add2 = ($pt_Add2 != "") ? $pt_Add2 . ", " : "";
  $pt_result_Add3 = ($pt_Add3 != "") ? $pt_Add3 . ", " : "";
  $pt_result_Add4 = ($pt_Add4 != "") ? $pt_Add4 . ", " : "";
  $pt_result_Add5 = ($pt_Add5 != "") ? $pt_Add5 : "";

  //concatenate the address
  $pt_Add_Conc = $pt_result_Add1 . $pt_result_Add2 . $pt_result_Add3 . $pt_result_Add4. $pt_result_Add5 ;

  ?>
    <tr>
      <td><?php echo $row_PartcipantsList['FirstName'] . " " . $row_PartcipantsList['Surname']; ?></td>
      <td><?php echo $row_PartcipantsList['EmailAddress']; ?></td>
      <td><?php echo $pt_Add_Conc; ?></td>
      <td><?php echo $row_PartcipantsList['Country']; ?></td>
      <td><?php echo $row_PartcipantsList['Phone']; ?></td>
      <td><?php echo $row_PartcipantsList['ReferedBy']; ?></td>
      <td><?php echo $row_PartcipantsList['PaymentMethod']; ?></td>
      <td><?php echo $row_PartcipantsList['ChargeAmount']; ?></td>
      <td><?php echo $row_PartcipantsList['PaidAmount']; ?></td>
      <td><?php echo $row_PartcipantsList['GroupID']; ?></td>
    </tr>

    <?php } while ($row_PartcipantsList = mysql_fetch_assoc($PartcipantsList)); ?>
  <?php } while ($row_GroupList = mysql_fetch_assoc($GroupList)); ?>

</table>



</body>
</html>
<?php
mysql_free_result($UserDetails);

mysql_free_result($GroupList);

mysql_free_result($PartcipantsList);
?>
```

Comment: and what you want from here? At least post your current code you tried?

Comment: Start by creating a SQL query that will use a JOIN to read the data from both tables and sort it by courseInfo.courseName and UserInfo.FirstName

Comment: Can your users only ever be on one course at a time?

Comment: can you tell us what you are using to connect to your db i.e. mysql, mysqli, pdo etc, and also if you are you using procedural or oop (if either is possible).

Comment: The users can only join one course at a time.

Comment: I added the code now.

Answer (score 0):

depending on whether you are using mysqli or mysql there are several ways you can handle this

**foreach(mysqli)**

```
$query = $db->query("SELECT * FROM.... WHERE ....");

$data = $db->get($query);

foreach($data as $key => $value) {

     echo '<li>'.$value["courseid"].'</li><br/><ul>';

     $courseid = $value["courseid"];

     $query2 = $db->query("SELECT * FROM `userinfo` WHERE `courseid` = '$courseid'");

     $data2 = $db->get($query2);

     if($data2 != null) {

          foreach($data2 as $key => $value) {

               echo '<li>'.$value["username"].'</li>';
          }
          echo '</ul>';
     }
}
```

Comment: I am using MySql. I tried the while, but that only gave me the list of courses, not the sub-list with participants, I was trying to work out whther this supposed to be a while within a while?

Answer (score 0):

you can do this by join these two tables as follow

```
    $q=mysql_query("SELECT C.CourseName,C.CourseStartDay,U.FirstName FROM CourseInfo AS C LEFT JOIN UserInfo AS U ON C.ID = U.CourseID");
    while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($q)) {
      /*echo the results*/
        echo $row["CourseName"]."</br>";
        echo $row["FirtsName"]."</br>";
     }
```

Comment: You should always avoid putting queries inside a loop where possible!

Comment: Thx. Can you please be more specific of how I can echo it in the way I need it?

Answer (score 0):

The straightforward way is quite easy. For each course, query the database using a `WHERE` clause on `UserInfo.CourseId` to get all the participants to this course, and display it.

(Btw, I find strange that a participant can only follow one course.)

The main downside of this method is that you need an extra query for each course you display. With 10 or so entries, that won't be a problem, but if you find yourself with hundreds, that can become problematic.

An optimized solution is to get all the courses and all the participants, and sort them using a small algorithm :

```
<?php
$link = // Connect to mysql using mysqli_connect()

// Get courses
$coursesResult = mysqli_query($link, 'SELECT * FROM CourseInfo');

// Get participants
$usersResult = mysqli_query($link, 'SELECT * FROM USerInfo');

$users = array();

// Sort users by course
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($link, $usersResult)) {
    // Create the entry
    if (!isset($courses[$row['courseID']]))
        $users[$row['courseID']] = array();

    // Add user to the list
    $users[$row['courseID']][] = array (
        'id' => $row['id'],
        'name' => $row['name'],
        // ...
    );
}

// Display user list along the courses
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($link, $coursesResult)) {
    echo 'This is course ' . $row['name'];
    echo 'Users are :'
    if (isset($users[$row['id']])) {
        foreach ($users[$row['id']] as $ulist) {
            echo '* ' . $users['name']
        }
    }
}
```